# Tapping cell in table view does not do anything

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have been having issues with selection in one of the table views in my app. Basically, the issue is that I can only segue to another view controller by tapping on cells that are the result of a search. For some reason I am unable to tap cells in the standard table view.

When I tap a cell normally, nothing happens. However if I search for a cell using the search bar, I can tap on cells and they will segue as intended to another view controller. I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
    if names.count == 0 {
        if enterButtonTapped == false {
            backgroundLabel.text = "Before you add any transactions, you must first set a budget. You can do this by tapping the 'Budget' tab."
        } else {
            backgroundLabel.text = "You haven't added any transactions yet. Tap the add button to add a new transaction."
        }
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        backgroundLabel.sizeToFit()
        backgroundLabel.hidden = false
        backgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        clearButton.enabled = false

        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        return 0
    } else {
        backgroundLabel.hidden = true
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
        clearButton.enabled = true
        return names.count
    }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        //println(searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
        var indexValue = names.indexOfObject(searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }
        //This works, unless there are two payments with the same name. To revert to previous version, remove tableView if statement and just keep code below the else.
    } else {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (names.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

The view controller is connected to the cell in the storyboard by a push segue.

Initially I wondered if it was this line (but it's not):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You most likely have one or more elements covering up the majority of the table view cell that are intercepting touches.

Comment: There are indeed elements over the cell, however they don't cover the entire thing so even tapping the empty space doesn't work. Also, surely if that was the case, it would also be an issue for the search results?

Comment: It seems that you have two table views - the search table view and the self.tableview.  I am assuming this because of the `if` at the top of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - but your are always dequeing cells from `self.tableview`. If you have multiple tableviews you should just pass `tableview` to `dequeueReusableCell...`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean in regards  to passing tableview to dequeueReusableCell?

Comment: There is a tableview parameter passed in to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - this is the tableview you are currently operating on, so you should call var `cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell`

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me the error - `unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard`

Comment: That means you haven't registered the prototype cell name against the other table view

Comment: Are you sure your segue is connected to the cell as a selection segue rather than a accessory action?

Comment: Can you check that have you set table view delegate object UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: @rdelmar How can I check? I just control clicked and dragged from the prototype cell to the view controller that I want to segue to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fairly simple actually. I just had to change the Selection setting within the table view attributes from 'No Selection' to 'Single Selection'.

Comment: Ffs just came across this exact problem with this exact solution.